# Shape of passed values blah indices imply blah

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I am attempting to pass my custom dataset which is loaded in from a CSV file using 
`panda.readcsv()` through sklearns MLPRegressor.

My initial error was my 1D array needed to become a 2D array. `Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 1.].`

So I used `panda.reshape(x_test, (-1, 1))` on both the x_test and y_train to solve this issue. However this now presents me with the following error.

`Shape of passed values is (16209258, 1), indices imply (207811, 78)`

Have looked around a few other posts without success.

Comment: More detail is so needed, but how about `panda.reshape(x_test, (-1, 78))`?

Comment: Not sure what detail you require? I implemented -1, 78 on x_test however this will not work on y_train/y_pred.

Comment: Of course it won't work on y_train. MLPRegressor usually outputs a 1D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I after implementing @Quang Hoang's suggestion  `panda.reshape(array_name, (-1, 78))` on `x_test`, `y_test` and `x_train` this finally converted all nessasary arrays into the required 2D format.